# Variables globales javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy haciendo una petición **AJAX** que me retorna un `json`, y necesito usar los valores del `json` fuera de la función **AJAX**, ojala que los datos fueran publicos o globales, y no logro como hacerlo.

Este es mi codigo:

```
$('#btnBusca').on("click",function () {

    var cod_sec = $('#txtcodsec').val();
    var fecha = new Date;
    var ano = fecha.getFullYear();
    var mes = fecha.getMonth();
    var num;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        data: {cod_sec: cod_sec,mes: mes, ano: ano},
        url: 'pagina.php',

        success: function (data) {
            var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
            num = parsedData[0].NUMERO;


        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Error peticion Ajax ');
        }
    });
    alert(num);
});
```

Quiero usar el valor de la variable `num` fuera de la función `$.ajax`.
¿Alguna idea de como hacerlo?

Comment: Necesitas esperar a que tu operación asincrona finalice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O simplemente puedes declarar la variable num fuera del evento click

```
var num;
$('#btnBusca').on("click",function () {

  var cod_sec = $('#txtcodsec').val();
  var fecha = new Date;
  var ano = fecha.getFullYear();
  var mes = fecha.getMonth();


  $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      data: {cod_sec: cod_sec,mes: mes, ano: ano},
      url: 'pagina.php',

      success: function (data) {
          var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
          num = parsedData[0].NUMERO;
      },
      error: function () {
          alert('Error peticion Ajax ');
      }
  });
  alert(num);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema no es el acceso a la variable, tu problema es el momento en el que accedes, dado que la peticion ajax se ejecuta de manera **asincrona**, cuando consultas la variable num, aun no tiene asignado un valor.

```
$('#btnBusca').on("click",function () {

    var cod_sec = $('#txtcodsec').val();
    var fecha = new Date;
    var ano = fecha.getFullYear();
    var mes = fecha.getMonth();
    var num;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        data: {cod_sec: cod_sec,mes: mes, ano: ano},
        url: 'pagina.php',

        success: function (data) {
            var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
            num = parsedData[0].NUMERO;


        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Error peticion Ajax ');
        }
    }).done(function(){

       alert(num);
    });

});
```

Comment: gracias, funciona. Pero ahora como hago para usar la variable "num"  en una nueva funcion fuera del ajax?

Comment: Las variables globales son generalmente una mala idea, pero puedes usar window.num = num; para guardarla global mente, e igual para acceder a ella alert(window.num);

Answer (score 1):

Como ya te han comentado, JavaScript [funciona de manera asíncrona](http://www.nauzethdez.com/js-9-programacion-asincrona/), no secuencial como la mayoría de lenguajes de programación. Es por esta razón que se suelen usar muchos callbacks en este lenguaje.

En realidad, la petición AJAX que estás haciendo y el `alert(num)` se ejecutan en el mismo período de tiempo. Es por esto que el valor de `num` sea `undefined`.

#### Soluciones

Las soluciones no son tan amplias, pero la mayoría existentes nos servirá en un amplio rango de situaciones. Veamos algunas.

1. Hacer una petición AJAX síncrona (tu peor alternativa): esta solución consiste simplemente en añadir la llave `async` con un valor `false` en los parámetros de la petición:

   ```
   let response = $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: 'destino',
       async: false
   }).responseText;
   // añadiendo la variable a window se hace global
   window.num = JSON.parse(response)[0];
   ```
2. Usar un polyfill para hacer uso de futuras características del lenguaje: Con la ayuda de [Babel](https://babel.io) podemos hacer uso de características futuras de JavaScript como lo es [Async/Await](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/understanding-javascript-async-await) por medio de [este plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-async-to-generator/):

   ```
   let response = await $.ajax({ /* ... */ });
   // o usando la API fetch
   let response = await fetch({
       method: 'GET',
       body: { ... },
       accept: 'application/json',
       'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   });
   ```

#### Namespaces

Usar variables globales [es una mala idea](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad). A medida que tu aplicación/web crece y añades librerías/frameworks, crece el riesgo de una colisión de variables, lo que aumenta el riesgo de un mal funcionamiento y una difícil depuración. Además, si se usan mal, podría desencadenar un [memory leak](http://javascript.info/tutorial/memory-leaks).

Usar un [namespace](https://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2013/04/27/javascript-namespaces-and-modules/) es una solución sencilla a este problema. Un namespace es un espacio en donde se almacena distintos datos relacionados entre sí (como en C#). En JavaScript no disponemos de ellos nativamente, pero podemos emularlos por medio de un objeto global que almacene en el datos relativos. Por ejemplo:

```
window.ventas = {
  desc: 0.25,
  iva: 0.18,
  hacerAlgo() {

  }
}
```

Aquí hemos creado un namespace que contiene valores e incluso una función que corresponden al namespace de ventas. Si bien lo agregamos al scope global, es mucho más limpio y seguro hacerlo de esta manera.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te está pasando es que cuando intentas acceder al valor de `num` aún no está disponible.

```
var ajax = function(cb) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'pagina.php',
    success: cb
  });
}

// callback para la llamada ajax
var callback = function(data, textStatus, xor) {
  var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
  num = parsedData[0].NUMERO;
}

ajax(callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

porque no intentas algo con un Promise de Javascript en jQuery. Acá te dejo una explicación de código.

```js
// Declaras un Promise
var num = $.Deferred().promise(); 
//Ejecutamos el promise con el when, y solicitamos por el get la URL que vamos a consumir, cuando se ejecute este GET entonces pasamos dos functiones que es: Exito y Fallo
$.when($.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/post/1')).then(exito,fallo);

function exito(data) {
   num = data;
   console.log("Tuvo éxito : " + num.userId);
 }
function fallo() {
   console.log("El promisse responde, no traje datos");
 };

//Con el metodo state(); puedes saber si tu promise aun este pendiente.
alert(num.state());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```